# OpenStack single node vs multi node

Tags: openstack

I'm totally new to openstack and after seeing tutorials running it on both single node and multi node(at least 3 consisting 1 controller 1 compute and 1 network node) i was wondering whats the diffrence and is there any advantages with multi nodes over single nodes ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open stack system consists of lot services. If you are running all these in single node , then
there will be resource scarcity issue unless you have a machine with very high CPU,RAM etc. Another advantage of multi node configuration is failover. In 3 node config if one node is down then you can continue with 2 nodes (provided you have service replication). Better go for at least 3 node config which is recommended by openstack.

Answer (score 0):

With Multinode configuration, you can achieve scale-out storage solution by adding more storage needs to your needs. Also, several compute nodes can be used to increase computation needs.